# вывод многомерного массива PHP методом рекурсии

Tags: php, массивы, рекурсия

Добрый день, задача такова: 
 Дан многомерный массив, нужно вывести все элементы массива в виде дерева, каждый уровень должен начинаться с двух пробелов и новой стройки.

```
$tree = [
"level 1" => ["level 1.1", "level 1.2"],
"level 2",
"level 3" => ["level 3.1", "level 3.2" => ["level 3.2.1", "level 3.2.2"], 
"level 3.3"],
"level 4" => ["level 4.1", "level 4.2", "level 4.3", "level 4.4"],
];
```

Никак не могу построить дерево, уже битый час сижу ломаю голову, нужны свежие идеи :)

```
function showTree($tree)
{
if (is_array($tree)) {
    foreach ($tree as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            echo $key;
        }
        showTree($value);
    }
    echo "\n\r";
} else {
    echo " $tree,";
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

для правильного формирования отступов вам нужно знать глубину рекурсии.

```
function printTree($data, $level = 0){
    foreach($data as $k => $v){
        $isArray = is_array($v);
        echo str_pad('', $level*2).($isArray ? $k : $v)."\n";
        if($isArray){
            printTree($v, $level + 1);
        }
    }
}

printTree($tree);
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю ещё один вариант в коллекцию ответов:

```
$tree = [
    "level 1" => ["level 1.1", "level 1.2"],
    "level 2",
    "level 3" => ["level 3.1", "level 3.2" => ["level 3.2.1", "level 3.2.2"], 
    "level 3.3"],
    "level 4" => ["level 4.1", "level 4.2", "level 4.3", "level 4.4"],
];

echo tree($tree);

function tree($array, $tab = '', $result = '')
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $result .= "{$tab}[$key] <i style='color:red;'>(array)</i><br>";
            $result .= tree($value, $tab . str_repeat('&nbsp;', 4));
        } else {
            $result .= "{$tab}[$key] => <b>$value</b><br>";
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Результат:

```
[level 1] (array)
    [0] => level 1.1
    [1] => level 1.2
[0] => level 2
[level 3] (array)
    [0] => level 3.1
    [level 3.2] (array)
        [0] => level 3.2.1
        [1] => level 3.2.2
    [1] => level 3.3
[level 4] (array)
    [0] => level 4.1
    [1] => level 4.2
    [2] => level 4.3
    [3] => level 4.4
```