# Добраться до последнего уровня массивов PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Есть многоуровневый массив типа

```
$arr = [
'a' => 1,
'b' => 2,
'c' => [
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => [
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2,
        'c' => [ 
            'd' => 3,
            'e' => 4,
            'f' => 5,
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Нужно добраться до последнего массива C и вернуть его
Понимаю, что нужна какая-то рекурсивная функция, но не понимаю, как ее написать. Поскольку это лишь пример, у меня массив может содержать и 10 уровней, и больше...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [вывод многомерного массива PHP методом рекурсии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/794459/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-php-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Comment: у вас в все ключи `c` называются? или они разные могут быть? среди элементов на одном уровне может быть только один массив? и он имеет ключ `с` или надо таки найти массив с максимальной вложенностью?

Comment: Да, все ключи называются одинаково. Нужно добраться до самого вложенного и вернуть его содержимое. На одном уровне может быть два или больше таких массивов

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из комментария автора: "мне нужно именно массив `с`, то есть последний который называется `с`"

```
 $arr = [
        'b' => 2,
        'c' => [
            'b' => 2,
            'c' => [
                'e' => 4,
                'f' => 5,
            ],
        ],
    ];

function findLastArray($array) {
    if (array_key_exists('c', $array) && is_array($array['c'])) {
        return findLastArray($array['c']);
    } else {
        return $array;
    }
}

$lastArray = findLastArray($arr);
```

Comment: Способ выше просто возвращает самый вложенный массив, а мне нужно именно массив `с`, то есть последний который называется `с`

Comment: Тогда нужно учитывать имена ключей и внутри цикла в условие добавить ` && $key === 'c'`. Внёс изменение в ответ

Comment: Переписал ещё раз. В вашем случае ещё проще, можно использовать функцию `array_key_exists`

Comment: Скорее имеется ввиду, нужно найти последний вложенный массив, а не конкретно `c` массив.  И если в массиве-массивов есть массив в котором больше нет массивов, вернуть. Иначе продолжить поиск.

Comment: Автор написал "мне нужно именно массив `с`, то есть последний который называется `с`"

Comment: Вы дочитайте до-конца. Автор пишет, что это просто пример. И если будут нюансы, у автора, с вашей функцией, возникнут разногласия. И начнутся опять повторные вопросы, как найти последний вложенный массив.

Comment: прочитайте первый комментарий к моему ответу

Comment: это не важно, важно то, что автор может не понимать, что он делает. Просто не знал, как задать вопрос, написал пример, но не понимает, как это работает. Лучше делать в таких случаях поиск не только `с` массивов, а также любого или только указанного. То есть ответ, должен быть более развернутым.

Comment: Автор может и не знает, что спрашивает, но мы же здесь решаем конкретную проблему, а не строим предположения о том, что проблема может быть на самом деле другая.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75306/discussion-between---and-and).